# Adding a search to leaflet map

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Basically I just want a search function like google maps, so you search a location or postcode and choose an option and you get the coords. Is this doable with leaflet maps?

Comment: This is called "geocoding". You can find plenty resources, including here on SO, and in Leaflet [plugins](http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#geocoding).

Comment: You can use leaflet search control.
Similar Question:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/130623/adding-a-search-box-to-a-leaflet-js-example